# Is "bug" a negative word when referred to a person?

Tags: nouns

I'd like to know if "bug" would sound negatively in cases like this "You're an IT bug" or "you're a languages bug", for example.

And, if not, could it be used negatively depending on the context, intonation, etc.?

Comment: Are you perhaps [conflating ***buff*** and ***bug***?](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=He%27s+a+history+buff%2CHe%27s+a+history+bug&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) As that chart shows, *He's a history **buff*** is a common sequence in English, but [*He's a history **bug***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22he%27s+a+history+bug%22) is all but unknown (that second link is to just ***three*** matching instances in the entire Google Books corpus). To my mind, it's so rare it has ***no*** "connotations" (apart from rarity! :)

Comment: As a native US English speaker, I have never heard the word *bug* used this way.  Did you see it used this way somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

I am native UK English speaker, and being 70 years old I'm maybe not familiar with youthful slang, but I've not heard "bug" used in a positive way. To me it implies either a defect in my code - "I have a bug to fix" or a person annoying me as in the phrase "stop bugging me". In other words, "bug" to me always has negative connotations.

I might instead use words such as: guru, master, maven, whiz, expert, or enthusiast.

Comment: I'm a native UK English speaker, and I'm aged 70, too, and I've heard of 'bug' used to mean 'enthusiast' or 'expert' in the 1940s and earlier, mainly in the US, and Merriam-Webster agrees: (Bug) 6 : ENTHUSIAST _a camera bug_, so I'd say not uncomplimentary but to be used with care because of possible regional incomprehension. - a 1925 quote: _To be perfectly frank he is a “radio bug.” He sits up in his suburban home o' nights and tunes in on everything from Montreal to Madrid._

Comment: Per my comment under the question, the obvious alternative is ***buff*** (only two letters to be changed! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I do find 'maven' used this way annoying.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: Even after visiting ELU & ELL most days for over 12 years, I still think I've had more exposure to ***maven*** from Stephen Pinker than from all other sources put together! I never knew the word before Pinker, and I've only just looked it up in a dictionary for the first time while writing this comment. I see it's "Chiefly US, of Yiddish origin", which is probably enough to explain why it irritates *me* (maven, schmaven,...).

Comment: @FumbleFingers -I've mainly seen it on the web, e.g. 'code maven', and mostly used by people who aren't _xxx mavens_.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey and Fumble - Nu, so what's wrong with *maven*?  Oy, a couple a kibbitzers who don't know from Yiddish...

Comment: @FumbleFingers & MichaelHarvey I'm a native BrE speaker soon to be 80 and I've never heard "bug" used other than in reference to insects and **shutter bug**  (Merriam Webster - a photography enthusiast). As for "maven" you finally spurred me into looking it up after all these years and it means exactly what I thought it did.

Comment: @PeterJennings: It's interesting you mention ***shutter bug*** - I knew there was something "quirkier" than ***camera bug***, and I couldn't really get my head around plain ***bug*** for that sense, but I couldn't call it to mind. It is one I've encountered occasionally, though. I definitely get the feeling the relatively uncommon US usage ***bug** = enthusiast* is mostly limited to "geeks with boys' toys" contexts. You might be a ***shutter / camera / CB radio bug***, but you probably wouldn't be a ***Victorian literature bug***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, maybe "mostly" limited to geeky things, but not exclusively.  There's also [*firebug* (arsonist/pyromaniac)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/firebug)

Comment: @Juhasz: We've had firebugs in BrE since at least the late 1800s, but that was originally AmE too. BrE doesn't use "bug" anywhere near as much as AmE though, so that's about the only one with any currency cisaltantic. I think it's also a kind of affectionate (kid's?) nickname in AmE (like Pumpkin?), where Brits have terms like Spud and Tosh. Or used to have. (I'm probably showing my age there! :)

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries indicate that "bug" used to mean enthusiast is dated slang, and not in current use.  It mostly seems to have been in the phrase "camera bug". In this sense it is generally positive, though it may also be used of someone who is too involved in their hobby, to the point of obsession.  You would have to read the context, since the meaning isn't present in the word in isolation.

Slightly more current is to use "bug" to mean hobby.  This is a jocular extension of the sense of "bug" as illness. The joke is that the hobby takes up all your time so is like a sickness.  Nevertheless, this sense is positive.  It suggests that the hobby is very good.

> He caught a bug eating raw fish.  (illness)

> He caught the skiing bug last year in Austria.  (jokingly describing the hobby as a illness)

But as for the original question.  Don't use "bug" like this it isn't used that way in modern English.